# How to get user information from several Linux servers using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I wanna get user information from several Linux servers, so I use `getent` module to get `passwd` information.

When I play below code, I can get all users from first server. But the second one is problem.

If the user information is same with first server like default user, (`root`, `bin`, ...) the information from second one didn't save in the file and in `ansible.log`, not `changed`, just `ok`.

```yaml
---
- name: Get all users in each servers
  hosts: linux
  serial: 1
  user: myuser
  become: true
  become_method: su
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Get all users
      getent:
        database: passwd
        split: ':'

    - name: Save it in file 
      lineinfile:
        path: myfile
        line: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value[1] }} ## get username and uid
      delegate_to: localhost
      loop: "{{ getent_passwd | dict2items }}"
```

Is there way to get all information? Help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

> *... the information from second one didn't save in the file ...*

Right, that seems to be the expected behavior because of the way you are using `loop`.

> *Is there way to get all information?*

You may take advantage from the following approach. A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - getent:
      database: passwd
      split: ':'

  - name: List of user per host
    debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}: {{ getent_passwd.keys() | join(',') }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [List of user per host] **********************
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg: 'test1.example.com: bin,root,user,<omitted>'
ok: [test2.example.com] =>
  msg: 'test2.example.com: bin,root,user,<omitted>'
```

and could be written into a file as follow

```yaml
  - name: Save it in file
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
    lineinfile:
      path: users.csv
      create: true
      line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}: {{ getent_passwd.keys() | join(',') }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```